# Has-Many and Belongs-to-one Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm trying to keep track of how many signup_conversions a user creates.
Therefore, I have those two following models:

#### signup_conversion.rb

```
class SignupConversion < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :convertee, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => 'convertee_id'
  attr_accessible :convertee_id
end
```

#### user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  belongs_to :signup_conversion
  has_many :signup_conversions
end
```

Would this work that way? Or am I missing something crucial here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried the code, but I give you some tips that hope you find useful.

- I think every `has_many`/`has_one` statement should have its correspondent `belongs_to`, so three `belongs_to` and one `has_many` doesn't look good.
- I'm not sure `has_one :signup_conversion` and `has_many :signup_conversions` would play well together, so I'd rather change the names. I changed the other names as well to try to make the associations clearer although I'm not sure I fully understand the real concepts they represent. You will probably come up with better names.
- By default, the foreign key is guessed adding the suffix `_id` to the association name, so you don't need to specify it in this case. Also, I don't think you need to make that attribute accessible, at least not for the association to work.

  **signup_conversion.rb**

  ```
  class SignupConversion < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :owner    , :class_name => "User"
    belongs_to :convertee, :class_name => "User"
  end
  ```

  **user.rb**

  ```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
    has_one  :owned_signup_conversion     , :class_name => "SignupConversion"
    has_many :triggered_signup_conversions, :class_name => "SignupConversion"
  end
  ```

Comment: This is what I've ended up doing - Worked perfectly fine! Thank you for pushing me into the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You have more code than you need here; you only need

```
class SignupConversion < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
   has_many :signup_conversions
end
```

Then you need a user_id column in your signup_conversions table, and you call

```
@user.signup_conversions
```

in your views or controller.

Comment: You didn't get the question: he needs both user and convertee relations... Its like a Post having many commenters (User object) and one Author (also a User object)

Comment: Yep, exactly - This only would be a regular has_many relation